# Modular arithmetic question square

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all $[x] \in \mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$ such that $[x]^2 = [x] $

I am really not sure how to start on this problem, please help me!

Comment: How about trying them all in a spreadsheet if you don't have any other idea?  Fill Series and Copy Down are your friends.

Comment: $x^2\equiv x\mod p$ where $p$ is prime means $x\equiv0 $ or $1\pmod p$.  $30=2\times3\times5$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^2 \equiv x\pmod{30}\iff x^2\equiv x\pmod{p}$ for $p=2,3,5$, and the latter only has $[0]_p$ and $[1]_p$ as solutions.